# Beautifulsoup get text based on nextSibling tag name

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping multiple pages that all have a similar format, but it changes a little here and there and there are no classes to use to search for what I need.

The format looks like this:

```
<div id="mainContent">

    <p>Some Text I don't want</p>
    <p>Some Text I don't want</p>
    <p>Some Text I don't want</p>
    <span> More text I don't want</span>
    <ul>...unordered-list items..</ul>

    <p>Text I WANT</p>
    <ol>...ordered-list items..</ol>

    <p>Text I WANT</p>
    <ol>...ordered-list items..</ol>

</div>
```

The number of ordered/unordered lists and other tags changes depending on the page, but what stays the same is I always want the text from the `<p>` tag that is the previous sibling of the `<ol>` tag.

What I'm trying (and isn't working) is:

```
main = soup.find("div", {"id":"mainContent"})

for d in main.children:
    if d.name == 'p' and d.nextSibling.name == 'ol':
        print(d.text)
    else:
        print("fail")
```

The out put of this is `fail` for every iteration. In trying to figure out why this isn't working I tried:

```
for d in main.children:
    if d.name == 'p':
        print(d.nextSibling.name)
    else:
        print("fail")
```

The output of this is something like:

```
fail
None
fail
None
fail
None
fail
fail
fail
fail
fail
None
fail
```

etc...

Why is this not working like I think it would? How could I get the text from a `<p>` element *only* if the next tag is `<ol>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want only the `p` tags which are before `ol` tag. Find the `ol` tags first and then find the previous [Tag](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag) objects which are in this case, the `p` tag. Now your code is not working because, there is a newline between the `Tag` elements which are [NavigableString](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) type objects. And `d.nextSibling` yields you those newlines also. So You have to check the type of the object here.

```
from bs4 import Tag
# create soup
# find the ols
ols = soup.find_all('ol')
for ol in ols:
     prev = ol.previous_sibling
     while(not isinstance(prev, Tag)):
         prev = prev.previous_sibling
     print(prev.text)
```

This will give you the text you want.

```
Text I WANT
Text I WANT
```

Comment: Ah hah! Thank you. I just found out I could accurately locate it by using `if d.nextSibling.nextSibling.name == 'ol':` but I couldn't figure out why I had to go two siblings to get the next sibling.

Comment: Yes, that will work too in this case. But what if traversing only two siblings is not enough? Because the `html` can be unpredictable. I think checking the object types is a good idea here.

Comment: I definitely agree. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use a *css selector*, i.e `ul ~ p` to find all the p tags preceded by the *ul*:

```
html = """<div id="mainContent">

    <p>Some Text I don't want</p>
    <p>Some Text I don't want</p>
    <p>Some Text I don't want</p>
    <span> More text I don't want</span>
    <ul>...unordered-list items..</ul>

    <p>Text I WANT</p>
    <ol>...ordered-list items..</ol>

    <p>Text I WANT</p>
    <ol>...ordered-list items..</ol>

</div>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)


print([p.text for p in soup.select("#mainContent  ul ~ p")])
```

Which will give you:

```
['Text I WANT', 'Text I WANT']
```

Or find the ol's and then look for the *previous sibling* p:

```
print([ol.find_previous_sibling("p").text for ol in soup.select("#mainContent ol")])
```

Which would also give you:

```
['Text I WANT', 'Text I WANT']
```

Comment: `print([p.text for p in soup.select("#mainContent  ul ~ p")])` works, +1 for the one liner. The second option you gave `print([ol.find_previous_sibling("p").text for ol in soup.select("#mainContent ol")])
` gives `TypeError: 'NavigableString' object is not callable`

Comment: @DjH, are you sure you used `find_previous_sibling("p")`, that error seems more like you did `previous_sibling("p")`.

Comment: Oh crap your right. Didn't copy paste it, just did and it works >.>

Comment: One is an attribute which gets the immediate preceding sibling, the other is a method that looks for what you pass, `ol.find_previous_sibling().text ` would also work in this case but using p would make sure that if something changed you would still get the preceding p sibling.